# Android get month as a two digit number

Tags: android, date

Hi does anyone know how to get the month as a two digit number for example 04 or 05?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
 dateFormat = "MM";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
 String month = sdf.format(date);
```

For more details please check [Formatting Month in Android](http://www.java-examples.com/formatting-month-using-simpledateformat)

Also check [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: this just comes out as 5 instead of 05

Answer (score 1):

HI :) what type of language that you use? javascript ou java?
in java you can try :

```
Date x=new Date();
System.out.println(x); // Fri Jun 05 22:43:25 BRT 2009
```

in javascript you can try:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple way is....

```
String date="1";

if(Integer.parseInt(date)<10)
{
date="0"+date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat to change how you want to display a date, code can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
and there is more about DateFormat Class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)